# Dynamically creating state and components from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) but my question is more general.

Consider the component below, which renders a button that toggles / collapses some text based on state:

```
function Example() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Button</Button>
      <Collapse in = { open }>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

I'm doing something similar, but for an arbitrary number of buttons and state values. My component receives an array, which I map through and return buttons. Easy enough, but then I must create unique state for each button so that toggling one doesn't trigger the others:

```
const updatedExample = ({ arr }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const buttons = arr.map((val, i) => (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen({})}> Button </Button>

      <Collapse in = { open } >
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      { buttons }
    </div>
  );
}

export default updatedExample;
```

I've tried various ideas, such as transforming the array to an object and setting that to state:

```
// arr === [2,6,9]
const newState = foo(arr) // {2: false, 6: false, 9: false}
const [open, setOpen] = useState(newState);
```

I felt that this might be the right approach, but I haven't been able to make it work. I've tried writing a reducer as well, which also failed. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you `useState(new Array(arr.length))`? use an array with the index being the element index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this problem would be to create a component that keeps track of its own state instead of having the parent keep track.

Here's an example of what that component might look like (looks very similar to the `Example` component you have in your question).

```
function ButtonWithCollapse() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(open => !open)}>Button</Button>
      <Collapse in={open}>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Using the component

```
function UpdateExample({ arr }) {
  return arr.map(item => <ButtonWithCollapse key={item} />)
}
```

Notice how we don't keep track of any state in the `UpdateExample` (parent) component but rather let each `ButtonWithCollapse` (child) component keep track of its own state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-browser-rk0nf

Answer (score 0):

If the state is only intended to open/collapse the text. You do not need to pass the array to Example(). Let's keep the state to each button.

After creating the Example() above, just render the array like this

```
<div>
{
  arr.map((val, i) => { return Example() })
}
</div>
```

Here's a code sandbox so you can play with it: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ives-j24y3

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track! Here's an example that accomplishes the task doing (pretty much) what you were considering doing (an object of values corresponding to your buttons).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const btns = ["bt1", "bt2", "bt3"];

function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState({});

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {btns.map(btn => {
        return (
          <div key={btn}>
            <button
              onClick={() => setActive({ ...active, [btn]: !active[btn] })}
            >
              {btn}
            </button>
            {active[btn] ? "on" : "off"}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Feel free to play with this in the [codesandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-ptolemy-q38r8).